# glossaries: .glo or .acn file for acronym? Was this changed recently?

Tags: glossaries

Please show me what I'm doing wrong if I'm making a mistake here, I think the package 'glossaries' was changed and it caused me problems.

I've been working on a Master Thesis for a while now, the list of acronyms used the glossaries package with acronym option. All acronym definition were made with \newacronym{}{}{}.

Running pdflatex on the report.tex file resulted in a report.glo file which could be used with makeglossaries to make the glossary entry.

I can track the versions since all were saved in dropbox and a week ago (17/6/14), the .glo files started coming up empty and .acn files appeared. I had to spend the better part of this afternoon to find out about these .acn files. Was this changed recently?

I checked that the .glo files contained only acronym information before they became empty and the contents are identical to the current .acn files.

Posting to save others the search.

Code to reproduce, now gives .acn with one entry and empty .glo, previously produced .glo with same entries.

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{tu}{TU}{Technical University}

\section{glossary}
%\printacronyms
\section{text}
\gls{tu} Master thesis.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `.glo` file contains the data for the main glossary. You have nothing for it, so it's empty; `makeglossaries` warns you with `Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you don't want to use the main glossary`. I don't think it's a recent change.

Comment: Also remember to call `makeglossaries` with the basename of the document, i.e. `report` instead of the more specific `report.acn` or `report.glo`. I guess you may have this wrong.

Comment: There have been some major changes to the `glossaries` package between v3.07 and v4.0, but none of them relate to the file extensions. The `acronym` option has always created the `acronym` glossary with the `acr` and `acn` extensions. As @egreg mentioned, add the `nomain` package option if you don't want the `.glo` file created. You might also want to take a look at [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs)